# How do I capture what is displayed on my camera surface area?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using a standard Android camera/surface area. I am not using the full screen, and have implemented the preview surface area with a height of 200dp. However, when I save the photo, it is saved as if the preview/surface area is the full screen.

Is there a way for me to save to a jpeg exactly what is displayed on the preview/surface area?

Some context for the question, I am using the camera to capture the text of a street sign, so I only need a very small image.

Comment: How do you know its save as a full screen?

Comment: because I can see the picture that is saved when I view it on the SD card.

Comment: I think when you view it in device then its occupy the screen that why? m I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my OCR applications I capture preview, and then extract subimages for further processing based on position of  ROI ( determined by some surface overlay ).

See android demo code ( demos/ ) : 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/

I'm not aware of interface allowing ti capture only subimage